# WPF/UWP Editor - "Properties" window looks strange

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I am working on an WPF app, and I saw this:

[image: Screenshot]

It is black color instead of normal color in some places. Every time I scroll it is also changes where it draws black.

Comment: based on my test, I can set the backcolor correctly. Can you provide a full screen gif to describe your problem? Also, you can see this picture.https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajMms.gif

Comment: can you explain your problem with more details??

Comment: MSFT, it is not what I asked about. This is not related to this. I mean the Properties window itself (I am Russian so I use Russian language, and "Свойства" is the Properties window). Here is the full screenshot: https://pingas.is-inside.me/XAG8u49z.png

Comment: Oh, GIF. Okay, here it is: https://imgur.com/a/0gmg9dE
Also in some WPF apps I have the same results (bottom): https://pingas.is-inside.me/Dix6Q0QG.png

Comment: @TheAirBlow, do you mean the color in the properties is always black? If so, I suggest that you can change your visual studio color to change it, please click options->General->color theme-> light.

Comment: MSFT, don't you see that it draws black in some places, not everywhere? And I do not want use Light Theme. Also, check the post again, there is a GIF of this behaviour.

Comment: Also I'll try to reinstall Visual Studio, this could help. But can anybody explain why some WPF apps have the same behaviour?